# Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am making some simple fetch with axios from **https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users** and I am using redux to store the state of the application. From the url upload I want to get all names in a dropdown list. But gives me that error from 2 days:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

Now I will provide below some pieces of code if you had seen before.

Here is the action, and I think that it is ok.

```
export const getAuthors = () => {
 return (dispatch) => {
axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then((response) => {
    dispatch({
      type: GET_AUTHORS,
      payload: response.data
    })
  })
  .catch(e => console.log(e))
 }}
```

Here is reducer and I think here it is the error:

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
console.log("ACTION", action.payload);
switch (action.type) {
    case GET_AUTHORS:
        return {...state, authors: action.payload}
    default:
        return state;
}
}
```

Here is the function component that shows the error:

```
const AddPostModal = ({authors, authorName}) => {
  return(
      <select
          value={authorName}
          onChange={handleChangeAuthor}
          {
             authors.map((author, index) => {
                return (
                   <option key={index}> {author.name} </option>
                )
             })
      </select>
  )
}
export default AddPostModal;
```

and below we have the class component:

```
import { getAuthors} from '../../actions/PostActions';
class Post extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      authorName: ''
    }
   }
   render() {
     return(
       <AddPostModal
         authors={this.props.author}
         authorName={this.state.authorName}
       />
     )
   }
  }
   const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
     return {
       authors: state.authorName.authors
     };
   }

   const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => (bindActionCreators({
     getAuthors: getAuthors,
   }, dispatch))

   export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Post);
```

Please if somebody have a solution, tell me because you will save my day. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API returns the result asynchronously so what you can do is a simple `null` check for `authors` first. Technically `.map()` can be called only on an array and `null` is throwing that error what you have seen in your solution.

Try the following:

```
<select value={authorName}
        onChange={handleChangeAuthor}>
          {
             authors && authors.map((author, index) => {
                return <option key={index}> {author.name} </option>
          })
</select>
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: The error is gone but the dropdown list is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Post` component `this.props.author` can be `null` or `undefined` based on situation. So I would prefer to call `AddPostModal` only when `this.props.author` is not `null` or `undefined` because `this.props.author` is kind of required for `AddPostModal`

On `Post` component:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
     return {
       authors: state.authorName.authors || []
     };
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your `initialState.authors` is `[]`. Second make sure your `state.authorsName` in `mapStateToProps` correctly points to the state of your `authorName` reducer. Otherwise, it should probably be like `authors: state.authors`.

Comment: I mapStateToProps if I get consol.log(state);. I will get this response: STATE: {authorName: Array(1), posts: {…}}.  I know is a small thing but I can't find what.

Comment: I assume `state.authorName` is pointing to the data from axios request. If so, the correct is `authors: state.authorName` instead of `state.authorName.authors`. If you console.log(state.authorName) what do you get?

Comment: If I console.log(state.authorName) I get State:[Array(10)]
0: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: Ok and what is in that array? console.log(state.authorName[0]). Is it the data you have requested?

Comment: yes exactly is the array I have requested, and if I do author: state.authorName[0] inside return block, still the dropdown is empty

Comment: If state.authorName is the data you want to pass to your component, then the issue should be fixed with `authors: state.authorName`. Also i noticed you have: `authors={this.props.author}` instead of `authors={this.props.authors}`

Comment: Yes I did as you said also I put authors={this.props.authors} instead of authors={this.props.author} and still empty. The strange thing is if I do: return <option key={index}> {author[0].name} </option> in AddPostModal, shows the first name in the dropdown, if I make return <option key={index}> {author.name} </option> list is empty

Comment: I solve it putting authors && authors.map((author, index) => {
                          return <option key={index}> {author.name} </option> on AddPostModal and return {
    authors: state.authorName[0]
  }; at mapStateToProps. Thank you